# Is there a word for the number of dimensions of a data set?

Tags: c#, set, naming, discrete-mathematics

I have some code that generates some code, and I want to store the number of dimensions of the resulting data structure in a variable. I'm looking for the right name for this variable. For example, `int` should have the value 0, `List<int>` should have the value 1, `List<List<int>>` should have the value 2, and so on.

Is there a word from set theory or otherwise that describes this number? (At first I thought it was cardinality but apparently that's the size of a set, not the nested-ness of the set....)

Comment: Might be more appropriate to ask here: http://math.stackexchange.com/ and I'm almost sure the term is dimensions, as in single dimension, 2-dimension, etc. I don't think there's another term for it.

Comment: @Ron: Ah, I thought that was only for "research-level" math questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word you are looking for, would seem to be [**rank**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28computer_programming%29)

> In computer programming, rank with no further specifications is
>   usually a synonym for (or refers to) "number of dimensions"; thus, a
>   bi-dimensional array has rank two, a three-dimensional array has rank
>   three and so on. Strictly, no formal definition can be provided which
>   applies to every programming language, since each of them has its own
>   concepts, semantics and terminology; the term may not even be
>   applicable or, to the contrary, applied with a very specific meaning
>   in the context of a given language.

The same term is also used in [linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)):

> In linear algebra, the rank of a matrix A is the size of the largest
>   collection of linearly independent columns of A (the column rank) or
>   the size of the largest collection of linearly independent rows of A
>   (the row rank). For every matrix, the column rank is equal to the row
>   rank. It is a measure of the "nondegenerateness" of the system of
>   linear equations and linear transformation encoded by A. There are
>   multiple equivalent definitions of rank. A matrix's rank is one of its
>   most fundamental characteristics.

Also refer to [this discussion on the definition of rank as related to sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190039/discussion-differing-definitions-for-the-rank-of-a-set) from the maths stackexchange.

Finally [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is how OPs employer names it for arrays :D

Comment: dimensionality looks like it'd also be accepted. I'd honestly just use a variable called numDimensions. It's clear, where as rank is correct, but pretty obscure.

Comment: refer to the last line. it is not that obscure